# Proving the lack of Perfect Forward Secrecy

Tags: key-exchange, protocol-analysis, forward-secrecy

In specific regarding the NSA's Key Exchange Algorithm, I read in an [analysis](https://eprint.iacr.org/2005/265.pdf) of the protocol that perfect forward secrecy cannot be provided.

Is there any way to prove or justify this? I couldn't find any documentation that showed why that PFS cannot be achieved.